# Request for improved vba code to execute a query in excel

Tags: excel, vba, search, filtering

would greatly appreciate any help to improve my macro.  I am new to vba and, although I found a solution for the scenario below, the code seems to be extensive especially when my goal is to be able to query a company database based on 100+ true/false criteria.

I have two worksheets:

ws1 = CompDB (list of companies with true/false statements)

CompDB

[image: 1]

ws2 = QueryDB (worksheet with query criteria and results)

QueryDB

[image: 2]

Sequence of events and desired outcome when query criteria in CompDB is changed and macro "Run Query" is executed:

1. If all cells within the query criteria are "False" then copy entire company database and paste to query results
2. If one or more cells within the query criteria are "True" then copy companies with "True" statements for any one of the "True" criteria
3. Sort query results alphabetically by company name
4. Remove duplicates from query results

Any suggestions to improve the code with loops or else would be greatly appreciated.  A few items that I can't figure out how to do more effectively:

Step 1: Way to find if all cells within the query are "False."  My code uses "and" statements which will result in a very long code in the event of 100+ query fields.

Step 2: Way to run the "if" statements for each query field with "True" value and return companies that meet this criteria without having to execute individual "if" statements, update the "LastRow" so results are pasted after every set of results.

Here is the code:

```vb
Option Explicit
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCompRow As Long
    
Sub Query() 'Run query
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1

LastCompRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
    
    With QueryDB
    
        'Code to check if all values in the criteria are false.  If yes, then copy entire company db to query results
        If .Range("D3").Value = False And .Range("E3").Value = False And .Range("F3").Value = False And .Range("G3").Value = False And .Range("H3").Value = False And .Range("I3").Value = False And .Range("J3").Value = False And .Range("K3").Value = False Then
                CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'Code to copy companies from CompBD that meet search criteria "True" to query results in the event one of the values in the query criteria is "True"
        If .Range("D3").Value = True Then
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If
        
        If .Range("E3").Value = True Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If
        
        If .Range("F3").Value = True Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If
        
        If .Range("G3").Value = True Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If
        
        If .Range("H3").Value = True Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If
        
        If .Range("I3").Value = True Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If

        If .Range("J3").Value = True Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If

        If .Range("K3").Value = True Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            CompDB.Range("A1:K" & LastCompRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="True"
            CompDB.Range("A2:K" & LastCompRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & LastRow)
        With CompDB
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        End If
    
    'Code to remove duplicates from query results
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A14:K" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    
    'Code to sort query results alphabetically by company name
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A14:K" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("B14"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ClearQueryResults() 'Clear previous query results

    With QueryDB
        .Range("A15:K99999").ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

I tried advanced filtering but it only returns companies that meet all "True" query fields vs each company that meets any one "True" criteria.

Comment: Try the Code Review stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: The code uses a counter to count the number of times True occurs in row 3 of sheet QueryDB. The counter can run through e.g. range D3:AZ3 without problems.
Step 2: The code loops through all cells in row 3 of QueryDB and checks if the cell value is True. Every time the cell value is True it loops through the corresponding column in sheet CompDB and checks if the cell value is True. If the value is True the code checks with WorksheetFunction.CountIf if the company already exists in the result range. Only companies that aren't already listed in the result range are added to the result.

The code clears the result range A15:K100 in sheet QueryDB. This range and some others are hardcoded but can easily be adapted according to the actual database.

```
Sub myquery()

' run the code in sheet QueryDB

Dim i, j, k, l, m, counter, LastRow, LastRowComp, LastCol As Long

With Sheets("QueryDB")

' clear result range from row 14 to row 100
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range(Cells(14, 1), Cells(100,11)).Clear

' initiate the row number of the result range
l = 15

' determine last col of row 2 in sheet QueryDB
LastCol = Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
' count how many times True occurs in row 3 of sheet QueryDB
For i = 4 To LastCol
If Cells(3, i).Value = "True" Then
counter = counter + 1
Else
End If
Next i

' if True occurs at least once in row 3 of sheet QueryDB then check sheet 
' CompDB else copy the whole data from QeryDB
If counter > 0 Then

' copy headers from CompDB to QueryDB row 14
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompDB").Range("A1:K1").Copy 
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A14")
' last row of sheet CompDB
LastRowComp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompDB").Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'run through cells of row 3 of sheet QueryDB and check cell value
For j = 4 To LastCol

' if true is found in cell of row 3 then run through the corresponding 
' column in sheet CompDB and check if cell content equals True

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Cells(3, j).Value = "True" Then

For k = 2 To LastRowComp

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompDB").Cells(k, j) = "True" Then
        ' check if company is already listed in the result range, if it 
        'isn't listed then add data
        If 

        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf 
        _(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB")._
        Range( Cells(15, 1), Cells(l, 1)), _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompDB").Cells(k, 1)) Then
        
        Else
        ' in  Range("A" & k, "K" & k) replace "K" with the last column of 
        ' the actual database
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompDB").Range("A" & k, "K" & k).Copy 
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A" & l)
        
        ' increase the row number for the output in the result range by 1
        l = l + 1
        
        End If
            
    Else
    End If

Next k

Else
End If

Next j

Else
' if all cells are False in row 3 of QueryDB then copy entire data 
' fromCompDB
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CompDB").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy 
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A14")

End If

' determine last row for sorting the data
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' in  Range("A14:K" & LastRow) replace K with the last column of the actual 
' database
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("A14:K" & LastRow).Sort 
Key1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryDB").Range("B14"), Order1:=xlAscending, 
Header:=xlYes

End With

End Sub
```

CompDB
[image: CompDB]

QueryDB
[image: QueryDB]